# brackets around multiline columns of a table

Tags: brackets

I am trying to reproduce the table of kinds of dreams in an early-modern philosophical [encyclopedia](http://books.google.com/ebooks/reader?id=lxY_AAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&pg=GBS.RA1-PT572).  Preserving the lineation within each column isn't necessary, but I would like to have the brackets align properly.  The following code handles everything except for the vertical alignment of the fourth columns.  The point on the bracket enclosing Externis/Internis should align with "physicum ortum," and there's a similar problem with Mediate/Immediate.  (It would also be nice if the line spacing in the columns were tighter.)  Suggestions?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\mbox{Somnium proprie dictum}
\begin{dcases}
  \mbox{Ordinarium}
    \begin{dcases}\mbox{Vulgare seu commune}\\\mbox{physicum ortum}\\
         \mbox{ex principiis}\\[2\jot]\mbox{Proprium
           aliquibus.}\\\mbox{Præsagiens}\end{dcases}
       \begin{dcases}\mbox{Externis}\\\mbox{Internis}\end{dcases}\\[2\jot]
   \mbox{Extraordinarium}
   \begin{dcases}\mbox{\greektext θεῖον\latintext }\mbox{ diuinum}\\
     \mbox{\greektext θεόπεμπτον\latintext}\\\mbox{immissum à
       Deo}\\[2\jot]\mbox{Diabolicum}\\\mbox{\greektext
       Δαιμονιόπεμπτον\latintext}\end{dcases}
         \begin{dcases}\mbox{Mediate per}\\\mbox{bonos
           angelos}\\[2\jot]\mbox{Immediate}\end{dcases} 
\end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx), and thank you for including a compilable example.  This probably part of the reason as to why you were able to get answers so quickly.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a modification to your setup that produces what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,english]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/babel
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools

\begin{document}

\[
\mbox{Somnium proprie dictum}
\begin{dcases}
  \mbox{Ordinarium}
    \begin{dcases}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        Vulgare seu commune\\[\jot]
        physicum ortum\\[\jot]
        ex principiis
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{dcases}
        \mbox{Externis}\\
        \mbox{Internis}
      \end{dcases}\\[2\jot]
      \mbox{Proprium aliquibus.}\\
      \mbox{Præsagiens}
    \end{dcases}\\[2\jot]
  \mbox{Extraordinarium}
    \begin{dcases}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        \greektext θεῖον\latintext diuinum\\[\jot]
        \greektext θεόπεμπτον\latintext\\[\jot]
        immissum à Deo
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{dcases}
        \mbox{Mediate per}\\
        \mbox{bonos angelos}\\[2\jot]
        \mbox{Immediate}
      \end{dcases}\\[2\jot]
      \mbox{Diabolicum}\\
      \mbox{\greektext Δαιμονιόπεμπτον\latintext}
    \end{dcases}
\end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}​
```

Note the use of `tabular` that switches to text mode, avoiding perpetual use of `\mbox`.

---

Here is an alternate version that does not use `dcases` and allows for spacing control vertically and horizontally (since it uses the standard `array` and `tabular` environments with an associated `@{}l@{}` column specification). The result is a much tighter presentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,english]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/babel
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\begin{document}

\[
  \text{Somnium proprie dictum}
  \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    \text{Ordinarium}
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        Vulgare seu commune\\
        physicum ortum\\
        ex principiis
      \end{tabular}
      \left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        Externis\\
        Internis
      \end{tabular}\right.\\[6\jot]
      \text{Proprium aliquibus.}\\
      \text{Præsagiens}
    \end{array}\right.\\[12\jot]
    \text{Extraordinarium}
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        \greektext θεῖον\latintext diuinum\\
        \greektext θεόπεμπτον\latintext\\
        immissum à Deo
      \end{tabular}
      \left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        Mediate per\\
        bonos angelos\\[\jot]
        Immediate
      \end{tabular}\right.\\[6\jot]
      \text{Diabolicum}\\
      \text{\greektext Δαιμονιόπεμπτον\latintext}
    \end{array}\right.
  \end{array}\right.
\]
\end{document}​
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different approach using a matrix (instead of cases) to fix the Externis/Internis "case".  (I did not understand what needed to be done in the second case.  You can compare the output with yours (which is first)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\mbox{Somnium proprie dictum}
\begin{dcases}
  \mbox{Ordinarium}
    \begin{dcases}\mbox{Vulgare seu commune}\\\mbox{physicum ortum}\\
         \mbox{ex principiis}\\[2\jot]\mbox{Proprium
           aliquibus.}\\\mbox{Præsagiens}\end{dcases}
       \begin{dcases}\mbox{Externis}\\\mbox{Internis}\end{dcases}\\[2\jot]
   \mbox{Extraordinarium}
   \begin{dcases}\mbox{\greektext θεῖον\latintext }\mbox{ diuinum}\\
     \mbox{\greektext θεόπεμπτον\latintext}\\\mbox{immissum à
       Deo}\\[2\jot]\mbox{Diabolicum}\\\mbox{\greektext
       Δαιμονιόπεμπτον\latintext}\end{dcases}
         \begin{dcases}\mbox{Mediate per}\\\mbox{bonos
           angelos}\\[2\jot]\mbox{Immediate}\end{dcases} 
\end{dcases}
\]

\[
\begin{matrix}
\mbox{Somnium proprie dictum} & 
\begin{dcases}
  \mbox{Ordinarium}
  \left\{
    \begin{matrix}
        \mbox{Vulgare seu commune}\\[-5pt]
    \mbox{physicum ortum} &     \left\{
       \begin{matrix}
       \mbox{Externis}\\
       \mbox{Internis}
       \end{matrix}
      \right.\\[-7pt]
         \mbox{ex principiis} \\
         \mbox{Proprium
           aliquibus.}\\
           \mbox{Præsagiens}
     \end{matrix}
\right.\\
   \mbox{Extraordinarium}
   \begin{dcases}\mbox{\greektext θεῖον\latintext }\mbox{ diuinum}\\
     \mbox{\greektext θεόπεμπτον\latintext}\\\mbox{immissum à
       Deo}\\[2\jot]\mbox{Diabolicum}\\\mbox{\greektext
       Δαιμονιόπεμπτον\latintext}\end{dcases}
         \begin{dcases}\mbox{Mediate per}\\\mbox{bonos
           angelos}\\[2\jot]\mbox{Immediate}\end{dcases} 
\end{dcases}
\end{matrix}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm amazed.  I go to the gym for an hour after posting, and on my return I find three solutions!  Many thanks to the three of you.